# Glitch-style animations using Core Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I'm looking to recreate some Glitch style animations I found in a video online:
http://videohive.net/item/outcome-glitch-slideshow/7494021

I want to use Core Animations to animate UIViews on and off the screen in the glitchy style presented in the video.

More specifically:  I'm looking for a way to split up a single UIView into multiple triangles of various sizes and animate each triangle independently.

I'd be happy with a pointer in  the right direction.

Comment: You can achieve this by animating number of UIBezierPath drawings with CoreAnimations, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `CAShapeLayer`, layer masks, and view screenshotting. To get triangles, form CAShapeLayers with the required path, apply these layers as masks to your view, and then capture this into a screenshot. You can then animate these triangular images with CoreAnimation.

Comment: I was afraid I was going to have to capture the UIView as a whole image, but masking the source view is a great solution. Thanks!